# Attaching to the the output of a running process

Tags: linux, ssh, stream

A process has been started remotely through a SSH session. The output stream (text) is displayed OK thru SSH. I would like to display the results locally without interrupting the running process.

Is there a way to attach to a running process and 'piggyback' a stream?

A Linux-only solution is acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to be able to kick start a remote process and view stdout,stderr of a remote machine running the process locally? right.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Use [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr):

> reptyr is a utility for taking an existing running program and
>   attaching it to a new terminal. Started a long-running process over
>   ssh, but have to leave and don't want to interrupt it? Just start a
>   screen, use reptyr to grab it, and then kill the ssh session and head
>   on home.

Or [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/):

> retty is a tiny tool that lets you attach processes running on other
>   terminals.